# a href in react opening subroute instead of new link

Tags: html, reactjs

item.link = "www.youtube.com"

```
 <a href = {item.link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{item.about}</a>
```

This tag is making a call to localhost:3000/www.youtube.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the "protocol" to link like `item.link = "http://www.youtube.com`

Will work as expected